# Encrypting web.config sections

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, web-config

In a .NET 4.0 website, which web.config sections can be encrypted?
I read that not all sections can be encrypted, but I can't find anything detailing which sections can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh8x3tas.aspx), it's clear that one can encrypt and decrypt a `web.config` **section** using the `Aspnet_regiis.exe` tool with the `–pe` option and the ***name of the configuration element*** to be encrypted as long as the section is not one of these ones:

> The following is a list of
>   configuration sections that cannot be encrypted using protected
>   configuration: ***processModel, runtime, mscorlib, startup,
>   system.runtime.remoting, configProtectedData, satelliteassemblies,
>   cryptographySettings, cryptoNameMapping, and cryptoClasses***. It is
>   recommended that you use other means of encrypting sensitive
>   information, such as the ASP.NET Set Registry console application
>   (Aspnet_setreg.exe) tool, to protect sensitive information in these
>   configuration sections.

Here's what you need to encrypt all other possible sections:

[Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Well, I'm encrypting the file programatically: _ConfigurationSection_.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider") ...

Comment: @ConradFrix that info was hard to find. The MSDN docs sometimes don't answer everything in one go. I think they should include this list in this link too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To Encrypt

go to below directory in command prompt 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>

1. Encrypt command for connectionStrings web config section and encrypt ShopAPI IIS application web.config file.

**aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/ShopAPI"**

**aspnet_regiis -pd "connectionStrings" -app "/ShopAPI"**

Answer (score 0):

Configuration files such as the `Web.config` file are often used to hold sensitive information, including **user names**, **passwords**, **db connection strings**, and **encryption keys**.That's why we should always keep those sensitive sections in encrypted form.

**Sections you can encrypt :**

- `<appSettings>`
- `<connectionStrings>`
- `<identity>`
- `<sessionState>`

**Sections you can't encrypt :**

- `<processModel>`
- `<runtime>`
- `<mscorlib>`
- `<startup>`
- `<system.runtime.remoting>`
- `<configProtectedData>`
- `<satelliteassemblies>`
- `<cryptographySettings>`
- `<cryptoNameMapping>`

> **Remember :** Encrypting and decrypting data incurs performance overhead.
>   To keep this overhead to a minimum, encrypt only the sections of your
>   configuration file that store sensitive data.